# expected primary-expression before ',' when writing gpio_pin

Tags: c++, freertos

i am new to c++ or freertos but i am trying to only use 1 pin to power an external led but i get the error

```
expected primary-expression before ',' token
     GPIO_PinWrite(led, led_pin, 0u)
```

i also get this ^^ with the other pin write

**this was fixed by deleting the semicoloms behind the define**

i don't specificaly know how to make an gpio pinWrite but i copied the one that is in the example of the baremetal function.

this is my task i am using an imxrt1050-evkb

```cpp
**this is standard import by MCUXpresso**
#include <stdio.h>
#include "board.h"
#include "peripherals.h"
#include "pin_mux.h"
#include "clock_config.h"
#include "MIMXRT1052.h"
#include "fsl_debug_console.h"

**this is freeRTOS**
#include "FreeRTOSConfig.h"
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"
#include "queue.h"


#define led SEMC_D12;
#define led_pin GPIO_EMC_34;

volatile bool g_pinSet = false;


void vOnOff(void *pvParameters)
{
    while(true){
            vTaskDelay(200);
            PRINTF("Hello led\n");
            if(g_pinSet)
            {
                GPIO_PinWrite(led, led_pin, 1u);
                g_pinSet = true;
            }
            else
            {
                GPIO_PinWrite(led, led_pin, 0u);
                g_pinSet = false;
            }

}

}
int main(void) {
     gpio_pin_config_t led_config = {kGPIO_DigitalOutput, 0, kGPIO_NoIntmode};
    /* Init board hardware. */
    BOARD_InitBootPins();
    BOARD_InitBootClocks();
    BOARD_InitBootPeripherals();
    /* Init FSL debug console. */
    BOARD_InitDebugConsole();

//    GPIO_PinInit(led , led_pin , &led_config);

    xTaskCreate(
            (TaskFunction_t) vOnOff,
            "task3",
            configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE,
            NULL,
            10,
            NULL
    );
    vTaskStartScheduler();
    return 0 ;
}
```

i believe the code here ^^ is all the good i use for this example becouse i am working in an sandbox with spaghetti code everywhere

as you can see in my code i got GPIO_PinInit commented i don't know if i need to use that?

i expect to send an signal on and of to an io pin

Comment: What is that extra `GPIO_PinWrite` in line 6 of `vOnOff`? remove that and u shall be fine

Comment: good question i think i copied something wrong i did remove that still get the same errors

Comment: I got no idea of the subject but I know a little C++. What strikes me is that led and led_pin are not declared anywhere. I think this could also explain the error.

Comment: they are but i forget them to add to the question sorry

Comment: @Marc Roelse What is it PRINTF("Hello led\n");? Is it a macro?

Comment: I scanned the code it seems to be ok, the problem shall exist in other parts, a missing `,` probably, re read the code and try to find it

Comment: Ok. I guess they are not defined correctly. Do you know where e.g. SEMC_D12 comes from? Are you sure this should not be a string, i.e. "SEMC_D12"? Or did you miss an import that defines what SEMC_D12 is?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow that is for my log/putty file so i can see it got into the correct task

Comment: @ErikNellessen it comes from my pin.map that is in FreeRTOS i tryed to comment this task and run it then it works so i don't think it is an problem with that and i tryed when you say to make it an string and then i get the same amount of errors

Comment: @hessamhedieh the perculier thing is when i comment the task my code works

Comment: From my point of view the error message still says that there is something wrong with either led or led_pin. What data structures do they represent? If they represent just Integers or Strings, could you try pasting the values directly, i.e. do something like GPIO_PinWrite(1, 2, 0u); and see if that works?

Comment: What part of the code exactly did you comment to make it work?

Comment: Remove semicolon from #defines

Comment: @ErikNellessen if i comment the if till the else it works

Comment: for the question i had @AnttiHaapala fixed it my code stil not works but that was my question

Comment: now i get the error that my variables are not right and that is what @ErikNellessen pointed out

Comment: i am new what should i do with this post now

Comment: @MarcRoelse since there are no answers yet you should edit your question to be an useful one.

Comment: @Marc I guess it could still help people if you post an answer to this question with the working code and mark it as the right answer, so they can see the solution if they have the same problem and find this question.

Comment: i am gone do that @AnttiHaapala and then when i have the working code i wil post that to help people that run into the same problem as me becouse i was also looking for this for half a day

Comment: Your question is bad since it does not have a *minimal* example. C.f. with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327358/define-causes-an-expected-primary-expression-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeRTOS is a RTOS abstraction - it has nothing to do with handling gpio.

```
#define led SEMC_D12;
#define led_pin GPIO_EMC_34;
```

Are invalid. There should be no `;` after the macro definition. Because there is `;`, compiler sees:

```
GPIO_PinWrite(SEMC_D12;, GPIO_EMC_34;, 0u)
```

and exists with compilation error.

The [MCUXpresso SDK API Reference Manual](https://mcuxpresso.nxp.com/api_doc/dev/329/group__lpc__gpio.html) says that:

> static void   GPIO_PinWrite (GPIO_Type *base, uint32_t port, uint32_t pin, uint8_t output)

I guess you need 4 parameters to `GPIO_PinWrite`, not 3.

Comment: thanks for the explanations of why there shouldn't be an ; behind define.

Comment: Because #define isn't handled by the compiler, it is handled by the preprocessor. for a statement #define q1 q2 all it does is literally replace every occurrence of q1 with q2. As said in the post, this would cause unnecessary semicolons to be placed in the code when it gets to compile time.